# How can i create method like this 'shold.be.a.integer' in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a class e.g.

```
class AnyClass {}
```

And I want create method on this class like this (like we use in Chai lib)

```
new AnyClass().should.be.a.integer
```

How can I create a method like this?

Comment: Within class you can make a object ```should``` in which further you can create a object ```be``` and inside ```be``` object ```a```  inside a method ```integer```.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object like this in your class.

```js
should = {
    be: {
        a: {
            integer: function(){} 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a method that check if a value is an integer, you can use this code

```
class AnyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.should = {
      be: {
        a: {
          integer: function(value){
            return !isNaN(value) // check value is a number
              && Number.isInteger(value); // check value is an integer
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```